# Java - Method Preconditions and postcondition enforcement

Tags: java, preconditions, post-conditions

My question is short. Are method preconditions and postconditions enforced by the compiler?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean, maybe with a simple example...

Comment: The question really is shot. Preconditions and postconditions can be virtually anything, and there's no way a compiler can read your mind.

Comment: This is a true false question on my study guide! Very confusing.

Comment: @JungleJeem What is your definition of 'precondition' and 'postcondition in the study guide? As a concept in java - there is no such think as precondition and postcondition, but it can be implemented using annotations I believe.

Comment: You can use valid4j with hamcrest-matchers (found on Maven Central as org.valid4j:valid4j) 

For preconditions and postconditions:

    import static org.valid4j.Assertive.*;

    this.myField = require(argument, notNullValue());
    this.myInteger = require(x, greaterThan(0));
    ...
    return ensure(result, isValid());

For input validation:

    import static org.valid4j.Validation.*;

    validate(argument, isValid(), otherwiseThrowing(InvalidException.class));

Links:

-  http://www.valid4j.org/
-  https://github.com/helsing/valid4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Contracts for Java](https://code.google.com/p/cofoja/), which helps enforing pre- and postconditions as well as invariants through annotations. But there's no compile-time-checking, only runtime as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

No. Java doesn't have explicit support for design-by-contract pre/postconditions like (for instance) Ada does. See [the java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#usage-conditions)